# Uninstalling Anaconda in Windows 10. After uninstalling I still have some big files.....Is it safe to manually delete it?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10, conda, uninstallation

Even after uninstalling Anaconda in Windows 10 using the **uninstall-anaconda.exe** which was in their main folder, there is almost 10 GB of space occupied by the 'pkgs' folder in
`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs`

Is it safe to manually delete all the files of this folder?

Looking forward for your suggestions!

Comment: Yes probably. The anaconda docs suggest they should be deleted before running the uninstaller. I guess this means the uninstaller doesn't touch them -- https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/  (I guess having uninstalled you are too late for Option B on that link without reinstalling...)

Comment: Your OS is Windows 10, correct?

Comment: @AlessiaM Yes, my OS is windows 10.

Comment: @mrblewog I have even tried re-installing anaconda and the installed anaconda clean then used that clean command but still, those files haven't been deleted!

Comment: Fair enough. No further suggestions from me I'm afraid. If you've been round that loop, try *renaming* that package folder (not deleting it), use your system normally for a few days, and if nothing breaks you can probably delete it.

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Cleanup utility built into Windows?

Comment: @AlessiaM Do you have a step-by-step link or something??

Comment: This is a step-by-step guide from the Microsoft forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/how-to-free-up-disk-space-in-windows/2458cc31-bd19-482f-ace5-7e3bd9da8098

Comment: Thanks, @AlessiaM for the link, I tried it just now but it does not give an option to delete 'pkgs' folder.